# TypeScript and void Q promises

Tags: typescript, q

What is the correct way to use **Q** promises with **TypeScript 1.6** if they are void?  That is, they don't represent a value.  For example:

```
return Q.Promise<void>((resolve,reject) => {
    resolve();
}
```

or

```
let deferred = Q.defer<void>();
deferred.resolve();
return deferred.promise;
```

The call to `resolve()` gets the error:

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
(parameter) resolve: (val: void | Q.IPromise<void>) => void
```

Note, the following works:

```
let deferred = Q.defer<string>();
deferred.resolve("Hello World");
return deferred.promise;
```

Is this just a bug in the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/q/Q.d.ts) typing (updated Aug 17, 2015 as of this writing) perhaps, or am I specifying it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q with TS1.6 I ended up using:

```
return Q.Promise<void>((resolve,reject) => {
    resolve(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no return value or I do not care about the return value, I have been using...

```
return Q.Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I get the same error with that:  `(parameter) resolve: (val: any) => void  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target`  Are you on a different revision of DefinitelyTyped by any chance?  Or TypeScript 1.6?

Comment: I am using `Q` in a node env w/ TS 1.6 I bring in Q like this: `import q = require('q');` and use it like this: `let d: Q.Deferred<any> = q.defer();` How are you importing `Q`?

Comment: I'm using the Visual Studio 2015 version of TypeScript 1.6, no import, just a script tag.  Perhaps VS is the difference..

Comment: @Brocco- you are one smooth operator.